# Integrity constraint violation in Magento custom module

Tags: sql, magento, exception, referential-integrity

I have a similar probelm to [Integrity constraint violation creating Product in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13113019) (unanswered) but I am creating a custom Observer that hooks into the catalog_product_save_after event - based on this tutorial: http://fishpig.co.uk/blog/custom-tabs-magento-product-admin.html

However whenever a new product is saved I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '22-1' for key 'UNQ_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID'
```

The config.xml looks like this:

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_after>
            <observers>
                <a1web_save_product_data>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>metricimperial/observer</class>
                    <method>saveProductData</method>
                </a1web_save_product_data>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_after>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

The outline of the class is like this:

```
<?php

class A1web_MetricImperialConverter_Model_Observer
{
    /**
     * Flag to stop observer executing more than once
     *
     * @var static bool
     */
    static protected $_singletonFlag = false;

     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function saveProductData(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if (!self::$_singletonFlag) {
               self::$_singletonFlag = true;

                $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

                //Custom updates made to product object here

                $product->save();
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the product model
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        return Mage::registry('product');
    }

    /**
     * Shortcut to getRequest
     *
     */
    protected function _getRequest()
    {
        return Mage::app()->getRequest();
    }
}
```

The product is saved correctly with the custom product data I'm adding - and once the product is saved the error does not occur on subsequent saves of the same product.  It is just when the product is first created the error occurs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's a bit peculiar to call product save during ... product save. What exactly does your observer do? The module name is only partially revealing as to its function. What you are trying to accomplish might be possible / better accomplished using attribute backend models.

Comment: Basically what @benmarks said. Make your changes but do not call save, magento will do it for you. You might want to clarify on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @DanielSloof he has to save, this is observing save after event.

Comment: @benmarks: I didn't really notice it but that was part of the point I was making... Why isn't it part of a save before event? We need more info :)

Comment: Hi guys - thanks for the feedback.  I'm doing a bunch of calculations based on a standard "weight" (decimal number) attribute and a second  "weight_display_option" (dropdown) attribute both supplied by the admin, to allow for loads of different types of mass/ weight combinations to be saved into a third "weight_display" (string) (complete with appropriate roundings & units), depending on the kind of product.  And a similar thing for length as well.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Instead of using `$product->save()` try using the resource model, a la `$product->getResource()->save($product)`.

The reason being `$product->save()` will re-trigger all save events, hence running whatever is saving the cataloginventory_stock and throwing the error.

Comment: Life saver answer for me!

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I'd recommend **not** using the `catalog_product_save_after` event. Instead, try using  `catalog_product_prepare_save` which is fired *after* the POST data is applied to the product, but *before* `->save()` is called. That way you don't have to mess with with saving or that ugly `$_singletonFlag`!

Also, with `catalog_product_prepare_save` you get the **HTTP Request** object inside the Observer Event. No need for `Mage::app()->getRequest()`. Woot!