# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '3262-1' for key 'UNQ_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID'

Tags: magento

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '3262-1' for key 'UNQ_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID'#

This appears when I am trying to add stock to my store, and obviously deletes what I have entered and doesn't let me add anything, help me fix this please, I'm not the most amazing on the computer, so please bare this in mind.

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Changing

```
$product->save();
```

to

```
$product->getResource()->save($product);
```

solved this problem for me

Comment: This resolved the issue for me. Because the custom module is using product->save instead of product->getResource->save. Thanks for this! :)

Comment: Actually replacing save with getresource>save made thing even worse for me. Product got saved but absolutely without any stock data.

Answer (score 6):

I have faced the same issue and debugging it since two days. finally I got the solution and fixed the issue.
This was occurred due to the inconsistency into database tables.

```
cataloginventory_stock_item
catalog_product_entity
```

I have removed the all inconsistency data using below query:

```
DELETE FROM cataloginventory_stock_item where product_id NOT IN (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity)
```

You can check how much records before perform the delete.

```
select count(*) from cataloginventory_stock_item where product_id NOT IN (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity)
```

May be this can help someone!

Answer (score 4):

This error you can look in magento forum.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/300959/
This is error with sql index link. Yuo can use `$product->getResource()->save($product);` for resolve this problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14152754/1844561

Answer (score 3):

It took me hours on google trying to find the correct info that was easy to follow for an amature like me. Eventually using different sources, I figured out what I needed to delete and where I needed to delete it. The below worked for me, hope it works for you.

1. Go to your database
2. Find the table named "cateloginventory_stock_item
3. Delete the last few records on the list (at the bottom of the table)

Voila! You should now be able to enter new products.

Answer (score 1):

1062 Duplicate entry '3262-1' for key 'UNQ_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID'#

from this its clear that there is some unique constraint and 3262 value already exist in data base.

I suggest you run reindexing and then check.

Basically some entry 3262 didnt got deleted from your stock table so a new entry is throwing error.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue and fix which I have applied is as follow :

**Error** : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '59457-1' for key 'UNQ_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID'

**Solution** : There is a table called eav_entity_store, you will have to modify a record where sku / product ID is mentioned, Increase the Increment ID to + 1
and update that record in database. Once you update the Increment ID then you will be able to add the stock.

**For Example:** If "eav_entity_store" table has last increment_last_id as = 730354, then 
I will have to update that record to 730355 and my problem will get resolved :)

**SQL Query**: update `eav_entity_store` set `increment_last_id` = '730355' where `eav_entity_store`.`entity_store_id` =$YourStoreID;

Answer (score 1):

if the error showing for the table 'cataloginventory_stock_item' having 'UNQ_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID' index,

then please sure that you are passing different product SKU from your script each time.because if you pass the same SKU then it will fetch the id of the product on the basis of that SKU and get the duplicate entry of that particular product id.
Also Never Use 
$product->save();
to

$product->getResource()->save($product);
because it will not update your product details completely.