# Magento error in product page: "Integrity constraint violation Duplicate entry for key"

Tags: php, sql, magento, magento-1.7

this morning I added alternative products to some existing ones I have in my magento web site and I receive this as result:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4-257-259' for key 'UNQ_CAT_PRD_LNK_LNK_TYPE_ID_PRD_ID_LNKED_PRD_ID'
```

What happened exactly? what does this mean?
thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integrity constraint violation in Magento custom module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113116/integrity-constraint-violation-in-magento-custom-module)

Comment: but I haven't changed anything in the code myself

Comment: How you did that manually of through import

Comment: I edited and added the products manually