# 1062 Duplicate entry for key UNQ_MAGE_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID

Tags: magento

While adding product in Magento I am getting following error.

```
1062 Duplicate entry '24678-1' for key 'UNQ_MAGE_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID
```

I have followed solutions explained here, [Integrity constraint violation in Magento custom module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113116/integrity-constraint-violation-in-magento-custom-module/14152754#14152754)

Even after deleting entries from table as explained above,I am getting same error.

I am using Enterprise version  1.11.0.0

Comment: Please check your  cataloginventory_stock_item tabel which have already save product_id. If already product_id existing in this table it meanse you have to delete it first or update this table when you save product data.

Comment: I already did that, still it didn't work. Products are adding successfully, but on top integrity error message comes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the same issue and debugging it since two days. finally I got the solution and fixed the issue.
This was occurred due to the inconsistency into database tables.

```
cataloginventory_stock_item
catalog_product_entity
```

I have removed the all inconsistency data using below query:

```
DELETE FROM cataloginventory_stock_item where product_id NOT IN (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity)
```

You can check how much records before perform the delete.

```
select count(*) from cataloginventory_stock_item where product_id NOT IN (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity)
```

Comment: Hmmm, I got zero results from your query, but still facing the issue on Magento 2.3.4